# Can the following VBA code subs be improved for faster calculation?

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Sub CAL()

  'Cleans the data before analysis by removing unwanted fields

    
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim rng         As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    
    Range("$H$1:$T$20000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
                                                  "Customer Informations", "Customer Sale Statistic", "=", "Date:", "Group:", "Level:", _
                                                    "Real Value - 001", "2", "7", "3", "9", "12", "Target:"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("H2:T20000").ClearContents
    
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End sub
```

Comment: How much time is it taking right now?

Comment: It takes about 1.5 seconds to complete. The times used was this one Dim StartTime as date

StartTime = Now()

'Do something incredible

msgbox round((now()-starttime)*24*60*60,0)

Comment: `It takes about 1.5 seconds to complete....` O_O. And you are losing sleep over 1.5 seconds? Forget about this and think how can we solve world hunger using Elon Musk's $6 billion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not much but it might help a bit to deactivate calculation (if there are formulas) and screen updating:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Range("$H$1:$T$20000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
                                              "Customer Informations", "Customer Sale Statistic", "=", "Date:", "Group:", "Level:", _
                                                "Real Value - 001", "2", "7", "3", "9", "12", "Target:"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("H2:T20000").ClearContents


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

---

Alternative using arrays

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define your sheet here
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long  ' find last used row in column H
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' define your criteria to clear
    Dim CriteriaArray() As Variant
    CriteriaArray = Array("Customer Informations", "Customer Sale Statistic", "=", "Date:", "Group:", "Level:", "Real Value - 001", "2", "7", "3", "9", "12", "Target:")
    
    ' call the function with your desired range and define which field (column) is checked for criteria, Field:=1 means the first column of the range
    ClearContentsByCriteria ContentRange:=ws.Range("H1", "T" & LastRow), Field:=1, Criteria:=CriteriaArray
End Sub

Public Sub ClearContentsByCriteria(ByVal ContentRange As Range, ByVal Field As Long, ByRef Criteria() As Variant)
    ' read criteria data field into array
    Dim CriteriaData As Variant
    CriteriaData = ContentRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=Field - 1).Value
    
    ' here we collect which ranges we want to clear
    Dim RangeToClear As Range
    
    ' loop through all the criteria data field to check against your criteria
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(CriteriaData, 1) To UBound(CriteriaData, 1)
        Dim Item As Variant
        For Each Item In Criteria  ' check against criteria
            If CStr(CriteriaData(iRow, 1)) = Item Then  ' remove the `Cstr` function if you want to check something else than strings.
                ' if criteria matched add the range to RangeToClear
                If RangeToClear Is Nothing Then
                    Set RangeToClear = ContentRange.Rows(iRow)
                Else
                    Set RangeToClear = Union(RangeToClear, ContentRange.Rows(iRow))
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Item
    Next iRow
    
    ' Check if something matched your criteria and clear it.
    If Not RangeToClear Is Nothing Then
        RangeToClear.ClearContents
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found to clear", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably want to look at using `SpecialCells` and only clearing the visible cells.  Otherwise, why filter first if you are clearing the entire range?

Comment: @Darrel H The clear contents clears the filtered information. Followed by the following code ActiveSheet.ShowAllData. Which displays the filtered information by removing the filter

Comment: @PEH No it did not help sorry. I have a call function that calls to turn off screen updating, sorry for not including it within the post.

Comment: @LJ Well filtering is always cost intensive. Probably reading the whole data into an array `DataArr = Range("H2:T20000").Value` and then looping over that array removing the desired information and writing the array back `Range("H2:T20000").Value = DataArr` could be faster. Give that a try.

Comment: @PEH I don't know how to do that data array loop thing.

Comment: @LJ see my edit for an example

Comment: I'll test it out and get back to you soon @PEH

Answer (score 0):

Does the Range always have 20000 rows of data? If not, you should make it dynamic by finding the last row of data. I'm not sure how much time this would save, but it's worth a shot.

```vb
Sub CAL()
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim rng         As Range
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    LastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("$H$1:$T$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
                                                  "Customer Informations", "Customer Sale Statistic", "=", "Date:", "Group:", "Level:", _
                                                    "Real Value - 001", "2", "7", "3", "9", "12", "Target:"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("H2:T" & LastRow).ClearContents
    
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End sub
```

Comment: This works amazing. can you explain the following lines;  LastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row & Range("H2:T" & LastRow).ClearContents

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. "LastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" defines the last row of data within your range. You are telling it to look at column H and count up from the bottom of your sheet until it finds the first cell with data which then gives you the last row." Rather than filtering 20,000 rows of data as in your original code it only filters the necessary rows with data in therefore hopefully speeding up your macro. "Range("H2:T" & LastRow).ClearContents" only clears the contents from the filtered data until the last row of data(rather than 20,000 of data).